# How to replace a local variable from calling a function with another

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how i can replace a variable in a function and calling that function with another. I'm doing a youtube feed that will display videos. Im wanting to load a function when a user clicks. I already am calling the function that will display a playlist, but i want to display another playlist when u click on a navigation link. I want to change the variable that loads the specific feed. any help would be much appreciated. thanks

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var feedUrl = "";

    function loadFeedAPI() {
        google.load("feeds", "1");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
    }

    function playVideo() {
        //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
        $(".youtubeThumb").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 640, innerHeight: 390 });
    };

    function initialize(feedUrl) {

        $(".youtubeFeed").empty();
        feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLlVlyGVtvuVlzDWbR0rXf1YnpJ9JL74FV";

        new google.feeds.lookupFeed(feedUrl, function (result) {

            if (result.error || !result.url) {
                $('#videocomm').hide();
                return;
            }

            // get the feed items
            var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(result.url);
            feed.setNumEntries(25);

            feed.load(function (result) {

                // write out the feed data
                var container = $(".youtubeFeed");
                var totalcount = result.feed.entries.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                    var vidhash = /=(.*)&(.*)$/.exec(entry.link)[1];
                    var videoParmeters = "?rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&amp?vq=hd1080;wmode=transparent";
                    var VidTitleMaxLength = 42;

                    var countVidTitleLength = entry.title.valueOf().length;
                    var joinName = entry.title.split(/[ ,]+/).join('');
                    var joinNameLength = joinName.valueOf().length;

                    var strtemp = entry.title.substr(0, VidTitleMaxLength) + "...";

                    console.log(strtemp + joinNameLength);

                    container.append('<li><div><a class="youtubeThumb"  href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidhash + videoParmeters + '"  title="' + entry.title + '"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + vidhash + '/2.jpg" /><br />' + '<p class="videoTitle">' + strtemp + '</p>' + '</a></div></li>\n');
                }
                playVideo();
            });
        });
    }
    function loadTest(feedUrl) {
        feedUrl.initialize("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLlVlyGVtvuVnAg43cejh4HGzap_MPRNhV");


        alert("hi");

        return false;
    }
    loadFeedAPI();
</script>


  <div id="navigation">
            <ul id="tsSideNavUL">
                <li><a href="javascript:initialize();">The Roots of Our Vine</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:loadTest();">A Soiree From Start to Finish</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Selling</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Enrolling</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question goes to a core concept of javascript, which you should probably read about, perhaps, more in depth. That said, you can't access variables inside one function from another, because a function creates an enclosing scope.  what you can do is put all of the functions onto an object.

```
var youtube = {
  feedUrl: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLlVlyGVtvuVlzDWbR0rXf1YnpJ9JL74FV",

  loadFeedApi: function() {
    google.load("feeds", "1");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
  },

  playVideo: function() {
    //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
    $(".youtubeThumb").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 640, innerHeight: 390 });
  },

  initialize: function (url) {

    $(".youtubeFeed").empty();
    var feedUrl = url || this.feedUrl;

    new google.feeds.lookupFeed(feedUrl, function (result) {

      if (result.error || !result.url) {
        $('#videocomm').hide();
        return;
      }

      // get the feed items
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(result.url);
      feed.setNumEntries(25);

      feed.load(function (result) {

      // write out the feed data
      var container = $(".youtubeFeed");
      var totalcount = result.feed.entries.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
         var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
         var vidhash = /=(.*)&(.*)$/.exec(entry.link)[1];
         var videoParmeters = "?rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&amp?vq=hd1080;wmode=transparent";
         var VidTitleMaxLength = 42;

         var countVidTitleLength = entry.title.valueOf().length;
         var joinName = entry.title.split(/[ ,]+/).join('');
         var joinNameLength = joinName.valueOf().length;

         var strtemp = entry.title.substr(0, VidTitleMaxLength) + "...";

         console.log(strtemp + joinNameLength);

         container.append('<li><div><a class="youtubeThumb"  href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidhash + videoParmeters + '"  title="' + entry.title + '"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + vidhash + '/2.jpg" /><br />' + '<p class="videoTitle">' + strtemp + '</p>' + '</a></div></li>\n');
       }
       playVideo();
     });
    });
  },

  loadTestUrl: function(url) {
    this.initialize(
      "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLlVlyGVtvuVnAg43cejh4HGzap_MPRNhV"
    );


    alert("hi");

    return false;
  }

}
```

and then your markup

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul id="tsSideNavUL">
    <li><a href="javascript:youtube.initialize();">The Roots of Our Vine</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:youtube.loadTest();">A Soiree From Start to Finish</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Selling</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enrolling</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

note the 'youtube' in the function call.

Comment: getting an error of ...Cannot read property 'lookupFeed' of undefined

Comment: nvrmind got it to work. just having problems now displaying it to the container

Comment: i dont want to have a to make a new section about append. But now im having problems havin the videos append to the container. any ideas?